# How to GET rest json return from filtered perpage and specific page wordpress API link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I can get data per page with link 
`myWeb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10`
 
 but how I can get data from page 2 and per_page=10,
 I wondering it would be like 
`myWeb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10?page=2` 
for 10 posts in page 2 but it's not work, does it need custom API in WP-API to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to pass the arguments like this

```
myWeb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&page=2
```

You can check all the available Arguments from here

```
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/
```

Thanks!